# Matching array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was playing with javaScript and found something confusing..

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];
var c = '1,2,3';

a==b // false
b==c // true
c==a // true
```

What is happening behind the scenes ? anybody know that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Which line is confusing? `a==b //false` or `b == c //true`?

Comment: Though [`b===c` returns `false`](https://jsfiddle.net/xpg3krzv/). [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Why not ask about `![] == [] // -> true?`

Comment: b==c .. @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Thanks for this @webdeb.. can you please tell me the answer also.. :| javascript is amazing...

Comment: I mean [he has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758179/542251) answered this?

Comment: @gauravmehla You could read how `x == y` should be implemented [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison). Your `b == c` comparison corresponds to step 9.

Comment: @gauravmehla I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Array* compared to another *array* is not the same because they are pointing at different memory addresses.

But an *array* compared to a *string* for equality (`b == c`), casts the array to a *string*; effectively, it's doing something similar to:

```
b.toString() === c
```

But with an identity comparison (`===`), it will also check the type of both variables, in which case `b === c` will render as `false`.

Answer (score 5):

Evidently arrays get cast to comma delimited strings when compared to strings. [UPDATE: as Sawant correctly states, it's calling the array's `toString()` method.] But arrays compared to arrays simply remain as arrays, and only the same instance will be equal to itself.

This is a good reason why you should always use `===` and never use `==`.

If you need to compare the arrays by the elements they contain, use the `isEqual` function from the lodash library.

Answer (score 3):

1. Comparing two objects (array), they are not the same!

   ```
   a==b // false
   ```
2. Comparing two strings, because an array compared to a string, will be casted to a string.

   ```
   b==c // true
   ```
3. The same as 2.

   ```
   c==a // true
   ```

When you compare with `==` the interpreter will try to make left-hand-side and right-hand-side the same type.

It will first format it to a `string -> number -> boolean`

So for example, comparing `![] == []`.

1. `![] == []`
2. `false == []`
3. `false == ""`
4. `false == false`

This are the steps the interpreter has to perform to come up with:

```
  ![] == [] // true
```

Because of all this, just use always the `===` operator, and it will be also much faster.